PostgreSQL の副問い合わせで「列が少なすぎる」とエラーになる場合がある
PostgreSQLで以下のような構成があった時

テーブルA:　testId, userId, subId, itemA1, itemA2, itemA3
テーブルB:　testId, userId, itemB1, itemB2

実行例1:
下記ですと、内部のSELECTで取得したtestIdと一致するテーブルAのレコードがとれました。
SELECT *
  FROM "テーブルA"
 WHERE "テーブルA"."testId"
    IN (
        SELECT "テーブルB"."testId"
          FROM "テーブルB"
         WHERE "テーブルB"."userId" IN (1,2,3)
       )
;

実行例2:
下記ですと、内部のSELECTで取得したtestIdとuserIdの組み合わせと一致するテーブルAのレコードが取れるかと思ったのですが、副問い合わせの列が少なすぎるとエラーとなります。
どの部分が不正となっているのでしょうか？
SELECT * FROM テーブルA
  WHERE (テーブルA.testId,テーブルA.userId)
  IN (
    SELECT (テーブルB.testId,テーブルB.userId) FROM テーブルB.userId IN (1,2,3）
  )
;


どちらのSQLも文法エラーになります。
実際にテストしたSQL文を記載してください。
例えば下記のようにすれば文法エラーはなくなります。
SELECT *
  FROM "テーブルA"
 WHERE "テーブルA"."testId"
    IN (
        SELECT "テーブルB"."testId"
          FROM "テーブルB"
         WHERE "テーブルB"."userId" IN (1,2,3)
       )
;

SELECT *
  FROM "テーブルA"
 WHERE ("テーブルA"."testId",
        "テーブルA"."userId")
    IN (
        SELECT "テーブルB"."testId",
               "テーブルB"."userId"
          FROM "テーブルB"
         WHERE "テーブルB"."userId" IN (1,2,3)
       )
;

また、"テーブルB"の"testId"、"userId"がプライマリーキーになっていれば下記のように表結合することもできます。
SELECT A.*
  FROM "テーブルA" A
  INNER JOIN "テーブルB" B
     ON B."testId" = A."testId"
    AND B."userId" = A."userId"
 WHERE A."userId" IN (1,2,3)
;

以上
追記）2024 10/3 18:50
余計なことですが最初のSQLは
"テーブルA" に ("testId","userId","subId") でプライマリーキーを作成しているのであれば、
IN を使用するよりも下記のように表結合してプライマリーキーを使用した方がレスポンスが速くなると思います。
SELECT A.*
  FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT "testId"
          FROM "テーブルB"
         WHERE "userId" IN (1,2,3)
       ) AS B
  INNER JOIN "テーブルA" AS A
     ON A."testId" = B."testId"
;

なお表の別名のキーワード AS は省略できます。
DISTINCT で 重複する行（"testId"）を一つにしています。
ご参考までに
追記２）2024 10/4 5:40
申し訳ありません。
「副問い合わせの列が少なすぎます」 について回答していませんでした。
下記のSQLを実行すると row という名前の１項目が表示されます。
IN の左には２項目あるのに右には１項目しかないので上記のエラーが発生します。
SELECT ("testId","userId") FROM "テーブルB" where "userId" in (1,2,3);

なぜ row という名前の１つの項目になるかは下記のドキュメントに説明があります。
SELECT ("testId","userId") は
SELECT ROW("testId","userId") のROWキーワードを省略した記述であるということです。
これは複合型のROW式構文（ROW構文）になります。
「8.16.2. 複合型の値の構成」 の最後の方に説明があります。
https://www.postgresql.jp/document/13/html/rowtypes.html#:~:text=PostgreSQL
これを何のために使うのかは私には良くわかりません。
以上

回答ありがとうございます。質問を一部修正いたしました。
副問い合わせについて回答ありがとうございます。同じ数ではないかと悩んでいたのですが、ROWという項目について不勉強でした。確かにSELECTした結果、１カラムにカンマ区切りで数値が２つ入ったデータとなっておりました。
なお、ご提案いただいたINとの処理時間を比較したところ、INNER JOIN 利用時のほうが早くなっておりました。勉強になりました。
